# C# - Remove Beginning of String then Splitting by a delimiter

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm having trouble performing an operation where I define a custom delimiter on a string using a substring, removing the first 5 characters of the string and then splitting the string by the delimiter.

```
string delimiterString = numbers.Substring(2, 1);
char delimiter = delimiterString[0];
string result[] = numbers.Remove(0, 5);
result = numbers.Split(delimiter);
```

The error I am getting is on the third line: `Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string.` The Split method seems to want a char array while remove wants a string and I'm having trouble converting between the two. Could anyone lend a hand?

Comment: you have to know the difference between `string & string[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split returns a string array (string[]) while Remove returns a string.  You need different variables to store these values:

```
string delimiterString = numbers.Substring(2, 1);
char delimiter = delimiterString[0];
string resultSource = numbers.Remove(0, 5);
string[] result = resultSource.Split(delimiter);
```

Also note that you misplaced the array brackets.  The sample code you posted shouldn't compile.

Comment: So in this case I need to get resultSource into result because the string I need to split is the one after I perform the Remove.

Comment: @noclist The sample code was incorrect -- a careless error on my part.  I have corrected it.  Of course, you need to call Split on resultSource, not on result.

Answer (score 1):

Removing characters from a string returns a string, not an array, and then you should split that string, not the original string.

Getting the delimiter can be done without the intermediate string, and the string where the beginning is removed can be used directly in the split, so it can be done i a single statement:

```
string[] result = numbers.Substring(5).Split(numbers[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Remove` returns a `string`.  `Not a string[]`

`Split` returns a `string[]`

So, you need to use to different variables for those two functions.